# How to Calculate the View matrix for a camera object

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix-inverse

I had an old project where i was calculating my view matrix like this

```
float4x4 world = m_Frame.GetWorldMat();

float4x4 orthoN = world;
orthoN.XAxis.x = world.XAxis.x;
orthoN.XAxis.y = world.YAxis.x;
orthoN.XAxis.z = world.ZAxis.x;

orthoN.YAxis.x = world.XAxis.y;
orthoN.YAxis.y = world.YAxis.y;
orthoN.YAxis.z = world.ZAxis.y;

orthoN.ZAxis.x = world.XAxis.z;
orthoN.ZAxis.y = world.YAxis.z;
orthoN.ZAxis.z = world.ZAxis.z;

orthoN.WAxis.x = -float3::dotProduct( world.XAxis, world.WAxis );
orthoN.WAxis.y = -float3::dotProduct( world.YAxis, world.WAxis );
orthoN.WAxis.z = -float3::dotProduct( world.ZAxis, world.WAxis );

m_mView = orthoN;
```

but now im trying to do it with openGL implementing the GLM library objects

i figured doing it this way would work

```
m_mView = glm::inverse( m_Frame.GetWorldMat() );
```

this didn't seem to work. am i doing something incorrect? if everything looks fine I will take the assumption i am doing something else wrong and its not my view.

example number results both ways:

my results were weird with the glm::inverse i got

```
1.0, -0.12, -0.85, 0.0,
0.0, 0.87, -0.85, 0.0,
0.0, -0.12, 0.14, 0.0,
0.0, -0.12, -0.85, 1.0
```

with the first method I got whole numbers

```
1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
5.0, 6.0, 4.0, 0.0,
35.0, 36.0, 36.0, 0.0,
-1250, -1255, -1285, 1.0
```

Comment: Have you taken into account that GLM is column-major? i.e. given an array of numbers, the first 4 form column 1, next 4 form column 2, and so on. This is true for accessors too; m[0][1] will give col-0, row-1 value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `m_Frame.GetWorldMat()` gives you view to world transform, you should invert the matrix to get the world to view transform. Both snippets do the same.

In the older code, you're doing this by transposing the upper 3x3 matrix, which shows that the original matrix consisted only rotation, since rotation is orthogonal, its inverse is its transpose. The origin translation is also inverted rightly.

In the second snippet you do the same using GLM only that it'll be slightly less performant since it doesn't know M is orthogonal (pure rotation); so instead of transposing it'll do a proper inverse operation using Cramer 's rule. If you want, you can avoid this by using the transpose function that GLM provides. Make sure you don't transpose the whole 4x4 matrix but only the upper 3x3 matrix. Then handle the origin translation separately as you did in the previous code.

However, as for the end result, both would give you the same output (approximately). You can verify this by printing them or inspecting the values in the debugger.

Comment: i added some example results above. putting them in comment looked really messy.. but both results did not match up